# PHP ereg_replace allow spaces

Tags: php, preg-replace

using preg_replace I want to allow only alphanumeric and spaces,
but  `ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9\w\]`  deletes all spaces.

What could I do in order to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Match against `[\W\S]` to match non-alphanumeric, non-space characters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you forgot a space

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\w\ ]
______________^
```

eg:

```
$returnValue = preg_replace('@[^A-Za-z0-9\w\ ]@', '', 'I forgot a %space!!!');
// I forgot a space
```